# Redirecionamento entre páginas com datatable(primefaces) sem perder os filtros

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, front-end

Eu tenho 3 páginas e elas são responsáveis ​​por buscar objetos em meus bancos de dados baseados no filtro de seleção da primeira página.

Meu site é sobre anúncios de carros e tem a seguinte estrutura:

- 1ª página: É responsável pelo filtro de seleção do usuário.
- 2ª página: É a página da datatable com os resultados do filtro da primeira página.
- 3ª página: É relacionado com os detalhes do carro

Eu usei `@SessionScoped` no meu projeto para ser capaz de fazer o que eu quero e "consegui" dessa forma, mas o problema é que quando eu estou na terceira, quarta, quinta página do `datatable`, ao clicar em uma linha de detalhes do anúncio e retornar para a página do `datatable`, em vez de ele retorna para a página que eu estava, ele retorna para a primeira não importa onde ela está. Ela sempre retorna para a primeira página...

Por causa disso, eu tentei mudar meu `bean` para usar `@ViewScoped`. Eu pensei que iria resolver o meu problema, mas quando eu volto a partir da terceira página do site para a segunda, a `datatable` perde os dados do filtro(por ser `@ViewScoped`).

Eu tenho usado o contexto `Lazyload`, mas acho que não importa para o caso.

Minha necessidade é que o usuário possa clicar em um anúncio e se ele quer voltar exatamente para a página que ele estava, ele consiga.

Answer (score 0):

Já tive um problema similar mas não foi especificamente com o PrimeFaces.
Você pode criar um entidade para a view que contenha os filtros de tua pagina e/ou "sub-entidades", no Spring é conhecida como View Object. Como você cria o VO no teu controller, é só armazenar em tua sessão a tua entidade de filtros e recuperar quando necessitar.
Fica algo do estilo:

FiltrosVO filtros = new FiltrosVO();

/* ARMAZENA FILTROS */
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
session.setAttribute("FILTROS", this.filtros);

/* RECUPERA FILTROS */
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession();
filtros  = session.getAttribute("FILTROS");